# Zeppelin fail to load mongodb collecttion with spark interpreter

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, mongodb-query, apache-zeppelin

I'm using zeppelin Version 0.8.0 , mongodb 4.0, spark 2.2.0, mongospark connector 2.2.4, mongo java driver 3.8

```
      sc.version
      import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark
      import com.mongodb.spark.config.{ReadConfig, WriteConfig}
      import com.mongodb.spark.sql._
      import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
      import org.bson.Document
      import collection.JavaConverters._
      import org.apache.zeppelin.display.angular.paragraphscope._
      import AngularElem._
      val readConfig = ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/", 
      "database" -> "test","collection" -> "Collection_f"))
      val zipDf = spark.sparkSession.read.mongo(readConfig).toDF()
```

gives:

```
      import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark 
      import com.mongodb.spark.config. 
      {ReadConfig, WriteConfig} import com.mongodb.spark.sql._ 
      import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
      import org.bson.Document 
      import collection.JavaConverters._ 
      import org.apache.zeppelin.display.angular.paragraphscope._ 
      import AngularElem._ 
      readConfig:com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig.Self= 
      ReadConfig(test,Collection_f,Some(mongo 
      db://127.0.0.1:27017/),1000,DefaultMongoPartitioner,Map(),15, 
      ReadPreferenceConfig(primary,None), 
      ReadConcernConfig(None), 
      AggregationConfig(None,None),false,true,250,true, 
      true) 
         org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
         Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 
         0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): 
         com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16820 
         (Location16820): 'Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, 
         but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass 
         allowDiskUse:true to opt in.' on server 127.0.0.1:27017. The full 
         response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Sort exceeded memory limit of 
         104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting 
         operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.", "code" : 16820, 
         "codeName" : "Location16820" }
```

I think that it's a problem depending on `allowDiskUse` variable. Where I can fix it to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solved by changing to 2.2.3 connector [enter link description here](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SPARK-200?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel)